# How do I stop a smoke simulation on a specific frame?

Tags: smoke-simulation

How do I stop the smoke domain on certain frame?

I have tried multiple ways it doesn't work at all..

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18402/for-smoke-how-can-i-take-certain-frame-of-smoke-and-use-as-initial-frame