# Is there a way to offset in time a scene's animation including physics and particle caches and markers?

Tags: animation, particles, smoke-simulation, dopesheet

[this is kind of an extension of [How to Offset a Particle cache in Time](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/41979/1259) ]

I am working on a complex animation with lots of moving parts, including multiple particle systems as well as two smoke simulations. I now realized I needed to adjust the timing near the beginning of the scene, for which I will need more frames. Moving all the keyframes to the right is no big deal in the Dope Sheet but can I also shift all the start/end times of physics and particle caches and emitters in a similarly easy manner? Or do I have to manually locate and adjust each and every frame number reference buried in the various object' properties?

---

Sidenote feature request in case there is no easy way to do this ATM:

Ideally, I think, whenever something requires a reference to a specific frame number, it should be possible to specify a marker instead. Add to that that it should be possible to select and move markers in the dope sheet together with keyframes and all would be well... right? ;)
Does that feature request already exists somewhere that I can vote on?